# Combination Identity Question

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

My textbooks wants me to prove this identity in order to proceed into further questions related to this identity but I tried several hours to prove this but i failed can somebody assist me?

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} {2n+1 \choose 2i} = 2^{2n}$$

Comment: Can you fix your summation notation, please? There are no limits.

Comment: How many even-sized subsets are there in a set of odd cardinality?

Comment: It is indeed hard to prove what is not true.  Try: $$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{2i}=4^n$$

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Here are two VERY useful hints!

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}=2^n$.

Also, $\displaystyle \binom{n}{i} = \binom{n}{n-i}$.

Also, I believe the right hand side should be $2^{2n}$.

Comment: Indeed $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n+1}{2k}=4^n$.